# Entity Framework ExecuteStoreQuery with anonymous type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, anonymous-types

I'm trying to create a generic method to get data from SQL Server by one stored procedure, but it doesn't return any data:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(string SQL)  
{
  string spName = "exec spGetData @SQL";
  var parametros = new object[]{
                                new SqlParameter("@SQL", SQL)
                              };
  IEnumerable<T> result;
  using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
  {
    result = from a in db.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<T>(spName, parametros).ToList() select a;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Why don't you add the stored procedure as a "function import" and use it directly, instead of using the `exec spGetData` using `ExecuteStoreQuery`?

Comment: I didn't understand what you told about "function import", I'm using Stored Procedures because I will get some records from database and I want put they in a typed object from my model. I think that SQL Server functions return only one result from some operation and not a lot of records. Could you post some example about your solution?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

EF handles stored procedures and creates entity result sets from the  *function mapping* of the stored proc result select to be consumed off of the EF context.

Steps

1. In the designer choose 'Update Model From Database`.
2. When you get to the page which allows one to add tables/views/stored procs select the stored proc of interest.
3. Once the wizard is finished EF will contain the stored proc in the `Model Browser` which can be displayed by right clicking the EF design surface and selecting `Model Browser`.
4. In the `Model Browser` look for the stored proc in the `Model Store` -> `Stored Procedures / Functions` folder. Verify that the mapping is good by looking at the `Model`-> `Function Imports` and that the result entity can be found in the `Complex Types` folder.

From there you can call your stored proc off of an EF context and it returns a list of the result set to the code.

---

I give a more thorough explanation on my blog article and provide hints and work arounds to some problems with complex entity failures : [Entity Framework Stored Procedure Instructions](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1158)